# run moment(new Date()) each second in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this code

```
import "./assets/styles/App.scss";
import moment from "moment";
import React from "react";

function App() {
  let date = moment(new Date()).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")

  return <div className="App">{date}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

My question is how can I update the date each second to re-render the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to register an interval to the browser when the component is mounted with the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) function.

> The setInterval() method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces, repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call.

The code would be the following:

```
const getFormattedCurrentDate = () => moment(new Date()).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(getFormattedCurrentDate());

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(getFormattedCurrentDate());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{date}</div>;
}
```

`date` is turned into state since React will rerender your component (and therefore show changes in the date) when you call `setDate`.

Remember to clear your interval when the component is unmounted by returning a cleanup function from `useEffect` using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval), else you'll provoke a memory leak.

> The global clearInterval() method cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by a call to setInterval().

Comment: I was going to write the same thing, but you were quicker. Probably I will suggest using a function to return current date in that particular format, to avoid duplication.

Comment: Good idea, I edited my answer

Comment: I did it and succeed. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use React state to trigger a re-render when the date updates.  Updating a variable inside of render will not trigger a re-render on it's own.

```
import "./assets/styles/App.scss";
import moment from "moment";
import React from "react";

function App() {
  //Component state
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(handleGetCurrentDate());

  //Component variables
  const delay = 1000;

  //Use effect loop to trigger re-render
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //Set timer with interval of 1 second
    let dateTimer = setTimeout(() => setDate(handleGetCurrentDate()), delay);

    // this will clear Timeout on component unmount
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(dateTimer);
    };
  }, []);
  
  //Component functions
  const handleGetCurrentDate = () => {
    const dateFormat = "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a";
    return moment().format(dateFormat);
  }

  return <div className="App">{date}</div>;
}

export default App;
```